# Возвращение кода вставленной записи из хранимой процедуры через out параметр

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Создаю таблицу

```sql
CREATE TABLE "USERDOORS" 
   (    "UDID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "UIC" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DOORTYPE" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "AUTOLOAD" NUMBER(3,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "USERDOORS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("UDID")
   );
```

Создаю пакет с DML-процедурами, в частности на вставку, в которая также получает идентификатор новой записи и возвращает его через out-параметр.

```sql
PROCEDURE INS_USERDOORS
  (
   in_UDID     IN USERDOORS.UDID%TYPE
  ,in_UIC      IN USERDOORS.UIC%TYPE
  ,in_DOORTYPE IN USERDOORS.DOORTYPE%TYPE
  ,in_AUTOLOAD IN USERDOORS.AUTOLOAD%TYPE
  ,out_UDID   OUT USERDOORS.UDID%TYPE
  ) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USERDOORS
      (
       UDID
      ,UIC
      ,DOORTYPE
      ,AUTOLOAD
      )
    VALUES
      (
       in_UDID
      ,in_UIC
      ,in_DOORTYPE
      ,in_AUTOLOAD
      )
      RETURNING
        UDID INTO out_UDID;
  END INS_USERDOORS;
```

Обновляю модель из базы данных, выбираю таблицу и нужные хранимые процедуры

[image: Скриншот модели на диаграмме]

Выполняю *Сопоставление хранимых процедур*

[image: Скриншот "Сведений о сопоставлении"]

Но при сборке получаю ошибку

> Привязка функции сопоставления задает функцию Хранилище EFModel.USERDOORS_PKG_INS_USERDOORS с неподдерживаемым параметром: OUT_UDID. Выходные параметры могут сопоставляться только через свойство RowsAffectedParameter. Для возвращения значений из вызова функции используются привязки к результату.

Непонятно, как именно нужно настроить сопоставление, чтобы можно было работать с out-параметрами. Мне бы даже интересно было, как просто проигнорировать out-параметр.

---

При поиске ответа я [нашёл](https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=20037) один обходный путь --- изменить процедуру вставки, сделав её функцией возвращающей `sys_refcursor`, содержащий искусственную выборку с одним полем содержащим идентификатор

```sql
FUNCTION INS_USERDOORS
  (
   in_UDID     IN USERDOORS.UDID%TYPE
  ,in_UIC      IN USERDOORS.UIC%TYPE
  ,in_DOORTYPE IN USERDOORS.DOORTYPE%TYPE
  ,in_AUTOLOAD IN USERDOORS.AUTOLOAD%TYPE
  )
  RETURN sys_refcursor 
  IS
    v_UDID  USERDOORS.UDID%TYPE;
    crs     sys_refcursor; 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USERDOORS
      (
       UDID
      ,UIC
      ,DOORTYPE
      ,AUTOLOAD
      )
    VALUES
      (
       in_UDID
      ,in_UIC
      ,in_DOORTYPE
      ,in_AUTOLOAD
      )
      RETURNING
        UDID INTO v_UDID;
    open crs for
      SELECT v_UDID AS UDID FROM DUAL;
    RETURN crs;
  END INS_USERDOORS;
```

Comment: Если это например `SQLite`, то там можно напрямую писать функции на языке программы, а потом биндить их. Вот из них можно организовать любую логику возврата.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос... Почему бы не сделать функцию, возвращающую просто `USERDOORS.UDID%TYPE`?

Comment: @Dmitry тогда удастся настроить сопоставление? Ну а вообще проблема в том, что уже есть множество процедур в стиле первой и если их можно будет не переписывать/дублировать все, будет хорошо.

Comment: Какое сопоставление? Для вашего ORM-фреймворка? Без понятия, я ими не пользуюсь. Просто моя идея в том, чтобы делать проще всегда, когда можно делать проще. У вас в функции сначала делается вставка, потом выбирается число, потом это число заворачивается в курсор, потом этот курсор возвращается, а потом он еще как-то должен обработаться. А в итоге все равно будет ровно одно число, потому что инсерт вставляет 1 строку. Вот и возвращайте сразу это число и получайте как результат.

Comment: @Dmitry, это не моя функция, я нашёл это вариант решения в интернете. И, да, мне нужно решение для Entity Framework , поэтому я указал его в тэгах. И помимо простоты, важнее чтобы решение было рабочим.

Comment: Как на стороне C# вызывается данная процедура? В тегах есть C#, в вопросе его нет.

Comment: @Anamnian, это происходит как-то само (ну т.е. EF за это отвечает) после вызова `dbcontext.SaveChanges()`